# hot water issues

Tags: water

We replaced our bathroom faucet after not having hot water for several years. The water worked fine for a few weeks, but the hot water has suddenly stopped. In the meantime, the pressure for the hot water in our kitchen was extremely low. We replaced the faucet and it worked fine for about a week. Now the hot and cold water is basically a dribble. 
The bathroom water line was full of calcium deposits and is now working again (at least for now). 
The kitchen faucet is one handle with a pull out sprayer. We have taken the aerator off the sprayer and removed some calcium debris,  but there is obviously more somewhere else. The problem is we don't know what to try next. Should we just buy a new faucet? My concern is that it might be cheaper than paying for a plumber. HELP!!

Comment: How would a new faucet help if you have debris in the line? Why did you not have hot water for several years? Did you try draining the hot water tank to see fi there is debris in it?

Comment: Disconnect the pull-out sprayer from the flexible line, there's a screen in there too.

Answer (score 1):

I would first flush each feed line by detaching them from the faucet and opening them to flow into a bucket until the water moves freely.

Then if you have any compressed air, you might be able to blow out the faucet backward (blow into the faucet outlet/aerator end).  This should blow any calcium debris out the rear of the faucet.  Of course you must open the faucet valve so the air can pass through it.  With luck, that will clear the faucet valve.

Then re-attach the feed lines and confirm that water flow has been restored through the faucet.  Of course if calcium continues to dislodge in the water line, the blockages may recur.

Answer (score 1):

How old is your water heater? Ultimately it sounds like the problem is coming from your water heater.  Corrosion settles in the bottom of the water heater tank. You can try flushing it out through the spigot at the bottom of the heater.Depending on how old your heater is and how much sediment there is inside you may just need a new one to solve the problem. If you do replace it a couple things you can do to prevent this from happening again is 1) replace anode rod every few years this is a long tube located at the top of the heater the which goes down in the tank and attracts minerals and impurities in the water and helps prevent sediment in bottom of tank. Eventually the rod will corrode and need to be replaced. You cando this youself you will need an impact wrench though. Secondly you can just run some water out the bottom of the heater about once a month, this will help to flush out the sediment and keep the tank clean.